# Sending multiple requests to Apache Tomcat Server using command line

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tomcat, servlets

My current application is something like this:
I have an application deployed on Apache Tomcat. It starts with an HTML page that has a link, which when clicked, will send SOAP messages between two Servlets.

I am looking for a command line way of sending that request, thereby bypassing the HTML page completely. The reason of this is that i can then send multiple requests simultaneously and can then have tomcat start multiple servlet threads to serve each of the requests.

Comment: Not exactly a commandline tool, but have you looked at JMeter? It namely sounds like that you're looking for a webapplication stress test tool.

Comment: This seems to be what i will be going ahead with

Comment: If you need a testing tool, you should probably be using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: Do you want me to repost the comment as an answer so that you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with using JMeter. It seems simple and easily configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a groovy script.

This page has an example on how to use a [WebClient](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/webautomation.html) to automate web tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) to send the request to your server.

Comment: Refer to my comment on the previous answer.

Comment: Currently, there are no comments on the other two answers, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is another option